# iOS AVPlayer flash a frame when seek a paused video

Tags: ios, avplayer, seektotime

AVPlayer is paused at 10.0 seconds, then after a while, call seekToTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(15.0, 1000) toleranceBefore:kCMTimeZero toleranceAfter:kCMTimeZero, the screen first show a frame at about 10.02 and then show the frame 15.0, it should not show the frame at 10.02 first. What should I do to avoid this flash?

Thanks in advance!